# Copy system tables from one database to another (SQL)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

Is there a way you can copy the system tables from an sql database (including Azure) to another database and simply rename the tables? Also how can you check the number of rows in a system table?

Comment: in short, you can use `BACKUP AND RESTORE`

Comment: By system tables, do you mean catalog views like `sys.objects`? You can get rowcounts with a query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.objects`. Add detail to your question as to what you are trying to accomplish as one does not copy and rename SQL Server system tables.